# Box2D - body's position is incorrect

Tags: java, position, jbox2d

I have window 640x480. I use 4 static bodies as edge of window, so nothing can't move over the edge of window. This is one of the 4 bodies,
30 pixels represent one meter, all of the bodies are programmed with following method, but at right edge is space.

```
BodyDef leftDef = new BodyDef();
leftDef.type = BodyType.STATIC;
leftDef.position.set(0, 480/30);
PolygonShape leftShape = new PolygonShape();
leftShape.setAsBox(0, 1000);        
Body left = world.createBody(leftDef);
FixtureDef leftFixture = new FixtureDef();
leftFixture.density = 1;
leftFixture.restitution = 0f;
leftFixture.shape = leftShape;
left.createFixture(leftFixture);


glOrtho(0, 640, 0, 480, 1, -1); // glOrtho setting
```

Sorry, but I can't post images so what can cause that space?

Comment: [link](http://www.imagehosting.cz/?v=beznzvzvz.jpg) Here you can see space between dynamic body move to right top corner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgotten add "f" in this line

```
leftDef.position.set(0, 480/30);
```

so code must be

```
leftDef.position.set(0, 480/30f);
```

Now everything work good